# Matlab: export contour plot as shapefile (for ArcGIS)

Tags: matlab, gis, matlab-figure, arcgis, shapefile

I have a contour plot of wind speeds over an area and I plotted them with contour.

```
[C,h] = contour(X,Y,Z,labels,'ShowText','on');
```

I also plotted points on that same region as

```
scatter(Lat,Lon,1,g_xy,'filled');
```

and I get the plot fine. I need now to export both the contour lines (and their associated Z values), and the points (and associated g_xy values) onto a shapefile to be read in ArcMap. I've tried `shapewrite()`. Here's a sample of the C from the contour:

```
    C'=
20                        10
     -86.7200792311765          40.1022024035438
     -86.7887439017497          40.1103844954622
     -86.7686464894118          40.1157769184285
```

So, I don't know how to make that the shapefile has both the lat/long of the contours and the values, and also how to export the points!

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you export the `(x,y,z)` coordinates to ArcGIS and generate the shapefile from there?

Comment: hi @Adriaan that could work too, but I need to create many shapefiles.

Comment: ArcGIS has a built-in Python module doesn't it? QGIS, a free client, does have that, and you could write a python macro to load all coordinate files and transform to a shapefile in one click I guess. I'd try http://gis.stackexchange.com for an automated way of doing that.